# MVC3. Razor. How to disable caching for Child Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, razor

How to disable action result caching for child action in asp.net MVC3 with razor engine?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can't disable caching for a child action, if the "parent" action has caching, as the whole result is cached.

Comment: Caching does not apply to child actions, unless you explicitly inject your own mechanism to cache the output.

Comment: In MVC3 you can cache child actions.

Comment: I want force no Cache output from child action. How to?

Comment: Yes, the first step is to disable caching for all parents, but if somebody in my team forget about it and will use in conjunction with cached parent.

Comment: That's called donut caching, and it does not work out of the box in MVC3, only the reverse (donut hole caching), caching child actions

Answer (score 0):

The MvcDonutCaching NuGet package provides donut caching support in MVC3. See http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/donut-output-caching-in-asp.net-mvc-3